# Generating Random Numbers in For Loop from External Class

Tags: java, loops, random

First of all, I apologize if this has been asked before and I couldn't find it. I scoured the depths of the internet looking for some guidance but did not come up successful.

In my programming II class we are working on creating a program for the lottery. We have created external classes (did that in the classroom) and have used the objects created in those classes in our driver. For this assignment, we are creating a program which outputs lottery numbers. The program asks the user if they are playing Pick 3, 4, or 5 and then is supposed to output a random number for each "ball". In one of the separate classes we have already imported and instantiated the randomizer. However, when I program the array and for loop, while it generates the proper number of printouts (3 printouts for 3, 4 printouts for 4, and 5 printouts for 5), a new number is not being generated for each loop. Instead, it is holding onto the first value and printing that out for each loop after. I've included my code below. Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryGame2 {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    //Declare and instantiate objects
    PickGame2 pick = new PickGame2();
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    pick.activate();

    //Ask for and obtain user input
    System.out.print("Are you playing Pick 3, Pick 4, or Pick 5? Enter number here: ");
    int numberOfGame=keyboard.nextInt();
    PickGame2[] gamenumber=new PickGame2 [numberOfGame];

    for (int i=0; i<gamenumber.length; ++i){
        int ball=pick.pullBall();
        System.out.println("Ball " + (i+1) + " is " + ball);
    }//Ending bracket of for loop

    //Close Scanner object
    keyboard.close();

  }//Ending bracket of main method
}//Ending bracket of class LotteryGame2
```

The external classes are as follows:

```
private int ball;
private Random randomizer;

public LotteryContainer(){
    this.ball=0;
    this.randomizer=new Random();
}//Ending bracket of constructor

public void activate(){
    this.ball=this.randomizer.nextInt(9) + 1;
}//Ending bracket of method activate

public int getBall(){
    return this.ball;
}//Ending bracket of method getBall
```

and

```
private LotteryContainer machine;

public PickGame2(){
    this.machine=new LotteryContainer();
}//Ending bracket of constructor

public void activate(){
    this.machine.activate();
}//Ending bracket of method activate

public int pullBall(){
    return this.machine.getBall();
}//Ending bracket of pullBall
```

Comment: The code you are showing creates an array and iterates it.
But there is not a single assignment to any of the array elements.
Are you lacking something like `gamenumber[i] = ... `?!

Comment: external classes:
 {
 
 private LotteryContainer machine;
 
 public PickGame2(){
  this.machine=new LotteryContainer();
 }
 
 public void activate(){
  this.machine.activate();
 }
 
 public int pullBall(){
  return this.machine.getBall();
 }
 
}

import java.util.Random;

public class LotteryContainer {
 
 private int ball;
 private Random randomizer;
 
 public LotteryContainer(){
  this.ball=0;
  this.randomizer=new Random();
 }
 
 public void activate(){
  this.ball=this.randomizer.nextInt(9) + 1;
 }
 
 public int getBall(){
  return this.ball;}

Comment: @GhostCat, I'm not sure what you mean as to it not having any assignments. gamenumber is entirely depending upon user input and then, based upon that input, the for loop prints out however many balls it needs to.

Comment: First of all: do not put information into unreadable comments. Update your question instead. And the problem is; given your current input, is simply impossible to guess what is going on.

Comment: @GhostCat, there's really no need to be rude at all. I'm simply asking for help in having my code generate random numbers. Everything else with it is working perfectly fine and not giving any errors.

Comment: Sorry, this isnt meant to be rude. I am just telling you what is expected from you. The point is: if we are supposed to help you, you have to make that possible. We can't solve problems out of the air ;-(

Comment: I've updated my question with the classes laid out better in a more legible manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your `PickGame2` class, you'll see that it uses a `LotteryContainer` for picking the balls. And the `LotteryContainer` has two methods - one that picks a number for the ball (`activate`) and one that returns the ball number that was picked (`getBall`). Since you only ever call `pullBall` in `PickGame2`, and `pullBall` only calls `getBall` from `LotteryContainer`, it means you never call the `activate` method which gets you a new ball.

Add a call to `activate` before every call to `pullBall`, and you'll get a different number printed each time.

(Actually, it's possible for a random number generator to generate the same number several times. I don't know what the specification of your homework was, but if it's supposed to simulate a "real" lottery where each ball is different, then just generating random numbers and displaying them is not enough).

Comment: So even though it has activate instantiated in the beginning of the program I'll need to add it in my loop, too?

At first I thought it just happened to come up with three of the same number randomly, but after running the program several times I realized that the number is being obtained on the first loop through and then being held onto for the subsequent loops.

Comment: @SMcGwier yes - look at what the methods do. The `getBall` method only returns the current value of a field. It doesn't change the field and doesn't do anything with the random number generator. Hence it will always return the same value unless you call `activate` again. A computer program only does what is written in it, not more and not less.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I realize now if I had the loop activated for the entire program that I wouldn't have to put that second activate in there, but that's not how I need the program to run. I'm new to programming (obviously), so any help I receive is greatly appreciated.